# LRU page replacement vs FIFO page replacement

Tags: fifo, lru, page-replacement

I was curious after conducting an experiment for a course. I have read in text that LRU was more efficient, but throughout all my testing that doesn't seem to be the case. Locality has a play with this correct? The file streams I used must have not followed closely enough the principle of locality, because otherwise LRU would be far more efficient, no?

Comment: Do either of these answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058403/why-is-lru-better-than-fifo or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930899/lru-vs-fifo-vs-random?

Comment: yeah so basically its just based on the situation

Comment: Pretty much, just depends on the situation.